# Dynamic component in routing not rendering in Vue after refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building simple app in Vue and just facing following problem. This is how looks my file with routing:

```
...
 {
    path: '/movies/:id',
    name: 'Movies',
    component: Movies,
    props: true,
  },
...
```

so basically when I click any movie in my app, it takes its id and renders dynamic component. The problem is when I refresh page for example `/movies/12345` there's blank site with only `div` with `app`id. I checked in console and the axios request works so I can get informations about movie but cannot render them.

I moved `<router-view>` from `Header` (which is in every component in views folder) to `App.js` but it didn't work. So the structure of files is:

```
 views
   Home
   ...
App.js
```

Does any one know where I made mistake?

Comment: Ideally after fetching the data on reload event you should set your state.. that will trigger a re-render of components. so are you doing it as per your state management implemented in your vue js app?

Comment: after fetching, whole object is saving in state of component, I think problem is somewhere else because in this component is also ```Header``` which also no render after refresh

Comment: ok well, I think I just solved this problem. One of function used data passed through router instead of fetched one, so Vue was generating error which blocked rendering. Anyway thanks for your time @bron10

Comment: Glad to learn and help